# Column level sum/aggregation in SAPUI5 GridTable

Tags: odata, aggregate, sapui5, calculated-columns

I need to sum/aggregate of finance data at the **bottom of Column** in `SAPUI5 GridTable`. I am populating finance data from `SAP HANA` based `odata services` but the service can not provide **Total** at the bottom of data set. Hence my `GridTable` not showing Total. Can you please provide sample code or idea how I can calculate and show **Total** in `UI5` application?

Answer (score 1):

You can use method: [attachRequestCompleted](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.Model.html#attachRequestCompleted) of the model and then find the sum by looping over the data.

Comment: link is broken, new link: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.Model/methods/attachRequestCompleted