# Read data from ODataModel in loop to calculate sum

Tags: odata, sapui5

I need to read data from ODataModel in loop to calculate values. So `oData.Read()` is not good for me as it will call `Asynchronously` and will call another method. I want to loop as like looping in `Array` and probably `oDataModel.getProperty()` can help me. I am executing below code in `Chrome Console` and getting below result.

```
m1 = this.getView().getModel("Model Name");
```

`m1.getProperty("/")`

Result is: 
 `Object {SEARCH('61451144935589051'): Object, SEARCH('61451144935589052'): Object, SEARCH('61451144935589053'): Object, SEARCH('61451144935589054'): Object, SEARCH('61451144935589055'): Object…}`

However if  I try with below code then getting `undefined` as output.

```
m1.getProperty("/SEARCH")
```

Answer (score 1):

It is absolutely correct that you get `undefined`. Obviously you have an entity type `SEARCH` with a single key and your model stores several entities of this entity type.

You can grab all data stored in your model and process it like in the appended code example. However this **strongly not recommended** as you put to much logic to the client. A better approach would be a function or even an extra entity at your OData service.

```
var data, i, name, names, sum;

data = m1.getProperty("/");
names = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(data);
sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < names.length; i += 1) {
    name = names[i];
    // you have to check for the correct entity
    if (/SEARCH/.test(name )) {
        sum += data[name].value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, is there any better idea about how can sum column level of a grid table.? And your other recommend approach is not clear to me,. Can you please provide some sample code?

Comment: I just found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41500043/column-level-sum-aggregation-in-sapui5-gridtable. Somehow it does not make sense to ask the same question with less information!